# overflow instead of saturation on 16bit add AVX2

Tags: c++, unsigned, intrinsics, integer-overflow, avx2

I want to add 2 unsigned vectors using AVX2

```
__m256i i1 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) si1);
__m256i i2 = _mm256_loadu_si256((__m256i *) si2);

__m256i result = _mm256_adds_epu16(i2, i1);
```

however I need to have overflow instead of saturation that `_mm256_adds_epu16` does to be identical with the non-vectorized code, is there any solution for that?

Comment: Use normal binary wrapping `_mm256_add_epi16` instead of saturating `adds`.

Comment: there is no normal `add` for unsigned

Comment: Two's complement and unsigned addition are the same binary operation, that's one of the reasons modern computers use two's complement.   As https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq mentions, the instructions can be used on signed or unsigned integers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normal binary wrapping `_mm256_add_epi16` instead of saturating `adds`.

Two's complement and unsigned addition/subtraction are the same binary operation, that's one of the reasons modern computers use two's complement.   As the [asm manual entry for `vpaddw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/paddb:paddw:paddd:paddq) mentions, the instructions can be used on signed or unsigned integers.  (The intrinsics guide entry doesn't mention signedness at all, so is less helpful at clearing up this confusion.)

Compares like `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` are sensitive to signedness, but math operations (and `cmpeq`) aren't.

---

The intrinsics names Intel chose might look like they're for *signed* integers specifically, but they always use `epi` or `si` for things that work equally on signed and unsigned elements.  But no, `epu` implies a specifically unsigned thing, while `epi` can be specifically signed operations or can be things that work equally on signed or unsigned.  Or things where signedness is irrelevant.

For example, `_mm_and_si128` is pure bitwise.  `_mm_srli_epi32` is a *logical* right shift, shifting in zeros, like an unsigned C shift.  Not copies of the sign bit, that's `_mm_srai_epi32` (shift right arithmetic by immediate).  Shuffles like `_mm_shuffle_epi32` just move data around in chunks.

Non-widening multiplication like `_mm_mullo_epi16` and `_mm_mullo_epi32` are also the same for signed or unsigned.  Only the high-half `_mm_mulhi_epu16` or widening multiplies `_mm_mul_epu32` have unsigned forms as counterparts to their specifically signed `epi16`/`32` forms.

That's also why 386 only added a scalar integer `imul ecx, esi` form, not also a `mul ecx, esi`, because only the FLAGS setting would differ, not the integer result.  And SIMD operations don't even have FLAGS outputs.

The intrinsics guide unhelpfully describes `_mm_mullo_epi16` as sign-extending and producing a 32-bit product, then truncating to the low 32-bit.  The [asm manual for `pmullw`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmullw) also describes it as signed that way, it seems talking about it as the companion to signed `pmulhw`.  (And has some bugs, like describing the AVX1 `VPMULLW xmm1, xmm2, xmm3/m128` form as multiplying 32-bit dword elements, probably a copy/paste error from `pmulld`)

And sometimes Intel's naming scheme is limited, like `_mm_maddubs_epi16` is a u8 x i8 => 16-bit widening multiply, adding pairs horizontally (with signed saturation).  I usually have to look up the intrinsic for `pmaddubsw` to remind myself that they named it after the output element width, not the inputs.  The inputs have different signedness so if they have to pick one, side, I guess it makes sense to name it for the output, with the signed saturation that can happen with some inputs, like for `pmaddwd`.